# Fail to save a string in NSUserDefaults not until retain it

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults, retain

I'm a newbie in objective-c.
I got a problem in saving a string from UITextField.

I declared a string in property and synthesize it which named "familyName" to store user's family name.
Then I want to save the familyName when the user press a button.

```
-(IBAction)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
{}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
familyName = inputFamilyName.text;  
NSLog(@"the user's family name is %@", familyName); //it works here.

if (inputFamilyName == textField) {
    [inputFamilyName resignFirstResponder];
}
return YES;
}

-(IBAction)goToNameWheel:(id)sender{

NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefault setObject:familyName forKey:@"family"];
[userDefault synchronize];
}
```

It crashes when it runs the saving code, it said "Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address = 0x......"

After that, I try another test to see what happens to familyName, then I wrote:

```
-(IBAction)test:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"1.the family name is %@", inputFamilyName.text); // This works...
NSLog(@"2.the family name is %@", familyName);} // This crashes...
```

Finally... I try to retain familyName in textFieldDidBeginEditing:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
familyName = inputFamilyName.text;  
NSLog(@"the user's family name is %@", familyName); //it works here.

if (inputFamilyName == textField) {
    [inputFamilyName resignFirstResponder];
}
[familyName retain]; // just added randomly...
return YES;
}
```

Then everything works fine, I can save the familyName, print it..etc..
My question is...what exactly happens here, why do I have to retain it? Anything wrong with my original code?
Thx for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
familyName = inputFamilyName.text;
```

You're not actually using the property. You're using an instance variable with the same name as your property, but without the memory management stuff.

What you should be doing is

```
self.familyName = inputFamilyName.text;
```

Then the property's retain will kick in, and you won't have to manually retain.

To make it harder to make the mistake, you could change your `@synthesize` statement to be:

```
@synthesize familyName = _familyName;
```

If you do that, then it means that the property called `familyName` will have an instance variable called `_familyName` backing it — which means it's a lot harder to accidentally type the wrong one accidentally, thus avoiding this mistake.